# Find such function of class $C^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

"Find a $C^{\infty}$ function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f'(x)|<1$ and $f(x)\neq x$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$."

I managed to find $f(x)=ln(1+e^x)$ but it was almost through trial and error process. Is there a methodical way to find such function? Could you also provide some other examples? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $f(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Comment: Write $f(x) = x + h(x)$. You need $h$ a nowhere vanishing function with $-2 < h'(x) < 0$ everywhere.

Comment: @ DanielFisher but this is an equivalent problem. Is there any methodical way to find such function $h$?

Comment: The general idea can be to take a function that tends to be asymptotically equivalent to $x$ but never equal and of bounded derivative (you can adjust for know coefficient). Finding $x$ of @Daniel Fischer can be found by integrating the inequality between $0$ and some $t$

Answer (score 1):

One way to find examples is to find smooth functions $g$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $0<g<1$ everywhere and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g <1.$ Then set

$$f(x)=x+1 -\int_{-\infty}^x g(t)\,dt.$$

We then have $f(x)>x$ for all $x$ and $f'(x)=1-g(x)\in(0,1)$ for all $x.$